# Is it possible to detect when IE ignores a whitespace text node from a xml document?

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, dom

I am trying to write a shim for the [text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762687.aspx) property of the IE XML DOM library, but I have come across an issue regarding formatting whitespace.

If I process the text property for the following XML

```javascript
var doc1 = load_ie('<root><a>A</a><b>B</b></root>')
var doc2 = load_ie('<root><a>A</a>   <b>B</b></root>');
```

they give different results:

```javascript
doc1.text // 'AB'
doc2.text // 'A B' - the multiple spaces are compressed to a single space
```

However, to my surprise, IE doesn't seem to acknowledge the spaces present in x2 even exist, like other browsers do:

```javascript
doc1.documentElement.childNodes.length // 2
doc2.documentElement.childNodes.length // 2 (I expected 3!)

var doc3 = load_ie('<root><a>A</a> c  <b>B</b></root>');
doc3.documentElement.childNodes.length // 3
```

If I run the tests on Google chrome the number of nodes in the doc2 case is 3 ("a" node, a text node with 3 spaces and the "b" node), similarly to how the doc3 case works. **How will I be able to write my shim if IE hides the whitespace node from me and I can't tell apart the first and second cases even though they need to return different results?**

---

Code for loading creating XML documents from strings:

```javascript
load_ie = function(xmlstr){
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.async=false;
    doc.loadXML(xmlstr);
    return doc;
}

load_w3c = function(xmlstr){
    var p = new DOMParser();
    return p.parseFromString(xmlstr, 'text/xml');
}
```

Bonus question:

I also can't get the example given on the MSDN docs to work either. According to it, the following XML

```javascript
var d = load_ie(
    '<root att="   123   a      ">\n' +
    '     <a>   a   a   </a>\n' +
    '   <!--   comment   b   -->\n' +
    '   <?pi   pi   c   ?>\n' +
    '   <![CDATA[   cdata   d   ]]>\n' +
    '   e   f\n' +
    '</root>'
 );
 d.text;
```

Should give

```javascript
"a a cdata d e f"
```

but instead I get

```javascript
"a   a       cdata   d   \n   e   f"
```

I wonder if I am missing something obvious that is causing the weird behavior in my part.

Comment: I think it may be possible to configure a XML parser to either collapse whitespace or not. Maybe the default setting for the XMLDOM object changed between when the docs were written and now.]

Comment: @millimoose: I don't think I can change the settings to prevent whitespace removal though - I am only going through this trouble to avoid breaking a legacy app and I fear I mike break something (I am pretty sure the default has always been to ignore whitespace-only nodes). That said, I am still baffled how IE can treat the ignored case differently, even though I apparently can't detect that the whitespace has been ignored...

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Explorer parsing method uses the MSXML API, which can be configured to [preserve or collapse whitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761353.aspx). The following code works for me in IE9:

```
load_ie = function(xmlstr){
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.async=false;
    doc.preserveWhiteSpace=true;
    doc.loadXML(xmlstr);
    return doc;
}

var doc = load_ie('<root><a>A</a>   <b>B</b></root>');
console.log(doc.documentElement.text.length === 5)
console.log(doc.documentElement.childNodes.length === 3);
console.log(doc.documentElement.childNodes[1].nodeTypeString === "text");
```

Comment: The current app doesn't preserve whitespace though, so I am afraid this change could break something. That said, if there is no other way to disambiguate between the doc1 and doc2 cases then I might have to resort to this.

Comment: I don't really know what exact behaviour you want the shim to have. (Or how it differs from `innerText`, and `textContent`.) As far as I can tell, "preserving" or "swallowing" white-space are your only options here. What you could do is just make your shim collapse white-space the way your app expects it.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I will need to use preserveWhitespaces anyway because other browsers don't support ignoring spaces. This should possibly work then.

Comment: I am facing the same issue have someone find the solution on this?? using preserveWhiteSpace=true does not work I want just as in Firefox a text node is created for whitespace similarly IE too should have text node for each whitespace reason been if there is two tag say <A></A> <B></B> the whitespace between A & B is ignored while rendering this is because firefox creates three tag A, B & additional TextNode here textnode has empty whitespace but in case of IE no such textnode is created..please suggest a solution

Comment: @user593029 That should be a new question, preferably phrased more clearly.